# "What time is it? At 8 o'clock"

Tags: phrasing

I am unsure about this phrasing, does answering the question "What time is it (now)?" by saying "At 8 o'clock" or "It's at 8 o'clock" sound natural?

Comment: Not really...we don't use 'at' unless we are specifying the hour when something will happen.

Comment: Why are you using the preposition “at”?

Comment: I wouldn't use it, but that's the phrase I heard, hence the question.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Did you hear the "(now)" or are you asking if that's a valid way to phrase it?

Answer (score 4):

Using "at" to answer "what time is it (now)" does not sound natural; it actually sounds incorrect.

We will use "at" to describe when an event will take place. For example:

> "When does the store open?"
>   "It opens at 7AM."
>
> "When will you be home?"
>   "I'll be back home at 6:00."
>
> "What time is the party?"
>   "It's at 10."

The natural way to answer the question "what time is it (now)?" if it's 9AM would be:

> "9" or "It's 9 o'clock"

If you said "At 9" I would think you misheard me and are talking about something that will happen later.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is a very good first answer, but would benefit greatly from a source, and possibly a link. In the meantime +1.

Comment: Don't overlook [Stands the Church clock at ten to three?](https://poetrysociety.org.uk/poems/the-old-vicarage-grantchester/)